# SQL Azure - Low performance of External Data Table with nvarchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure

I can't find out the reason for a `select` query against an `external data table` being so dramatically longer than a direct query against the same table.

The schema of the table is as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [WebApp].[TestTable]
(
    [TestTableId] [int] NULL,
    -- some other int columns
    [Body] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [ExternalInterface])
```

The `external data source` refers to the database located in the same resource group and location.

Direct querying of a total of 70k rows completes in 1second.
A query against the external table will take up to 20 minutes.

Removing the `body` column from the select will cut the total time to several seconds. So definitely it has to do with the amount of data transfered.

I guess something goes wrong with my configuration. I just don't believe the elastic query engine can be so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've managed to sort this out by casting the `nvarchar(max)` column to a `nvarchar(n)` .

`SELECT [TestTableId], cast([Body] as nvarchar(3000)) from WebApp.TestTable`

Alternatively, specifying the max-length for the `Body` column on the target table will also do.

`alter table WebApp.TestTable alter column Body nvarchar(3000)`

SQL considers the data in `nvarchar(max)` columns as large objects and for some reason the performance of external tables which contain LOB columns is just desperately bad...

Comment: Thanks man, this saved my day. ;). I reduced a query from 3 minutes to.... 3 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Using elastic tables with Varchar(max) or Nvarchar(Max) causes huge delays. You have to change the source table to Varchar with whatever you max data length is, and then change the Elastic table to match.  If you do not change both it will error.

This is easy to test just by running a query that includes those fields, then one that does not include those fields, you will see big difference. My simple query went from 35 minutes to 11 seconds just by this one fix.